# parfor extremely slow with system call

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, system-calls, parfor

I have a MATLAB loop that looks something like this:

```
S = zeros(20, 1);
for i = 1:1:20
  system(command)
  S(i) = fetch_results_of_command_from_file()
end
```

where command is a string for a system call which runs a python command, fetch...gets results of the system call, and it's shoved into a return vector S.

Some details: 'command' calls a python script.  That script reads some data from a file, then performs an optimization procedure, then writes results back to file.  The python script is small - less than 1,000 lines - and on a shared disk.  All commands call this, but use different input data - one input file per worker.  The optimization itself is a single thread.  The cores are are all residing on a local machine which has over 40 CPUs, 2 cores each.

Each iteration of this loop runs in about 2 minutes, and everything is fine, but slow.

I am on a local machine with over 20 cores, and so I want to parallelize my code as such:

```
S = zeros(20, 1);
parfor i = 1:1:20
  system(command)
  S(i) = fetch_results_of_command_from_file()
end
```

It seems each system call deploys to a different processor just fine.  I would expect this loop to run on an order of 2 minutes + a little overhead time for the parfor loop, since it can be embarrassingly parallelized.

Unfortunately, no system call finishes in over 10 minutes (it never even gets to the fetch command).  Somehow, parfor is slowing every command down, as though it were being called in serial.  I do have the parallel toolbox installed, so that shouldn't be the problem.  What could be going on?

Comment: Are you missing `parfor` in a couple of places?

Comment: Are you doing disk I/O for example?

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose your problem without knowing anything really about what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.  Now that you mention it, there is disk I/O in the system call as well, but only once at the beginning.

Comment: You need to show the actual code you're running, on both the Matlab and python side.

Comment: I added some more details.  I don't want to dive down a whole rabbit hole of what's going on in the system(command), I am running a simple ML algorithm, but if you have questions I can add more details.

Comment: The python side is quite long.  Also, can you please slow down on writing so many comments and maybe write one condensed comment?  I feel like this comment thread is getting spammy-looking quickly.

Comment: You really should be more specific. One file between all the commands? How big is it? How many locations do you read from? Is the optimization using multiple cores already? How are the cores connected?

Comment: I have added details about the command being called.  I am happy to add whatever details help diagnose the problem, I just didn't know which details were most relevant and helpful.

Comment: You have a potentially very complex problem here, so the M may not be synonymous with "small", just "smallest". Not posting enough is a much greater violation of mcve, but I understand your situation and will keep asking.

Comment: There are several comments/questions I have about your approach: 1) What is your `parpool` size? Does it make use of _all_ available processors? 2) Why are you using `system` and not the [`python API`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html) directly? 3) Did you try to profile your code within a single iteration, to look for bottlenecks? 4) How can you rule out that your RAM or hard drive are the bottlenecks? In conclusion - if you want an answer, you must show us more code.